# AngularJS : save a clicked action of the selected row in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Summary :**

I have an **`array of objects`** that i am displaying into the **`ng-repeat`** list. Each object having three properties `id`,`name` & `age`. `name` field is clickable.

[image]

**Requirement :**

Once user clicked on the `name` field **`<a>`** tag should be removed from the table for that particular record that has been clicked.

Let's say i clicked on `Alpha` then link should be removed from this field.

[image]

**Problem Statement :**

Suppose user clicked previously on the `Alpha` and now he is going to click `Beta`. Then state of `Alpha` field again changed to previous state(`<a>` tag has been added).

[image]

Once `<a>` tag has been removed it should not be added again for that particular field.

**I tried so far :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.people = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Alpha",
    age: "24"
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Beta",
    age: "25"
    }
];

$scope.removeLink = function(index) {
  $scope.rowIndex = index;
};

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td ng-show="rowIndex != $index">
        <a href="" ng-click="removeLink($index)">{{person.name}}         </a>
        </td>
        <td ng-show="rowIndex == $index">
          {{person.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to handle is to have a **`field`** for the hyperlink to be true or false, when clicked make it **`true`**,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.people = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Alpha",
    age: "24",
    clicked : false
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Beta",
    age: "25",
    clicked : false
    }
];

$scope.removeLink = function(person) {
 person.clicked = true;
};

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td ng-if="!person.clicked">
        <a href="" ng-click="removeLink(person)">{{person.name}}         </a>
        </td>
        <td ng-if="person.clicked">
          {{person.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's just a problem statement I am facing the issue in angular ui-grid. How I achieve this in angular ui-grid as there is no ng-repeat.

Comment: then why your question has ng-repeat?

Comment: It is just a problem statement. I can not paste the whole `ui-grid` code here. this is the only reason i used ng-repeat in the post.

Comment: you should replicate the problem with your question. otherwise i dont think we can help. what you can do is create a plunker app with ng grid and post

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct as it is working fine as per my current question.

Comment: that is ok, but hope your actual problem is sorted